# user and group not getting set correctly for auto generated files

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php, ownership

I am hosting a Magento 2 (onlineshop software) project on my dev machine.

The user and group are set to this:

```
user -> company
group -> www-data
```

In Magento 2 some files are getting auto generated on runtime for example when I reload a site.
But the permission of auto generated files looks like this:

```
company@server:/srv/www/vhosts/company_m2/generated/code$ ls -lah
total 64K
drwxrwxr-x  16 company  www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:28 .
drwxrwxr-x   4 company  www-data 4,0K Mär  3 13:50 ..
drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:27 ADM
drwxrwxr-x   8 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:28 Amasty
drwxrwxr-x   4 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:27 Amazon
drwxrwxr-x   3 black   sudo     4,0K Mär  3 14:28 Composer
drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:27 Dotdigitalgroup
drwxrwxr-x   3 black   sudo     4,0K Mär  3 14:28 EthanYehuda
drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:27 Ho
drwxrwxr-x 107 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:28 Magento
drwxrwxr-x   5 black   sudo     4,0K Mär  3 14:28 Migration
drwxrwxr-x   3 black   sudo     4,0K Mär  3 14:28 PayPal
drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:27 Psr
drwxrwxr-x   3 black   sudo     4,0K Mär  3 14:28 Symfony
drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data 4,0K Mär  3 14:27 Vertex
```

As you can see there are three different user:group combinations:

```
company  www-data
www-data www-data
black   sudo
```

How can I change it so that it always uses the combination `company  www-data`?

---

Update:

I changed the apache user to `company` in `/etc/apache2/envvars` by overwriting

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=company
```

Like seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/164787/538817).

I also followed the advice from @unxnut and set the permission of the upper folder to `drwxrwsr-x` with `chmod 2775`.

Now if new files are getting generated it looks like this:

```
drwxrwsr-x  18 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 .
drwxrwxr-x   4 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:30 ..
drwxrwsr-x   3 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 ADM
drwxrwsr-x   3 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Aheadworks
drwxrwsr-x  13 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Amasty
drwxrwsr-x   4 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Amazon
drwxrwsr-x   3 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Composer
drwxrwsr-x   4 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Dotdigitalgroup
drwxrwsr-x   3 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 EthanYehuda
drwxrwsr-x   3 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Ho
drwxrwsr-x   3 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Klarna
drwxrwsr-x 118 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Magento
drwxrwsr-x   5 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Migration
drwxrwsr-x   3 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 PayPal
drwxrwsr-x   3 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Psr
drwxrwsr-x   3 black   www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Symfony
drwxrwsr-x   3 company www-data 4,0K Mär  3 18:50 Vertex
```

The user is still set to `black` instead of `company` on many folders though.

I don't feel like this all should be necessary. There must be a bigger underlying cause. I have another server hosted on rackspeed where no folder at all has the sgid or suid bit set and it works like a charm there.

Comment: Check the permission bits on the directory in which files are created.  You may have to modify the suid/sgid bits on directory.  You cannot modify the owner but may be able to modify the group.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have set the folder to `drwxrwsr-x` with `chmod 2775`. I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

When any user creates new files or directories, they will normally be owned by that user. For regular users, this cannot be changed. For `root` (or user with access to the `CAP_CHOWN` capability), changing the file owner is possible... but a program still needs to explicitly make the system call to change the owner. Usually only programs intended for mass backup/restore of files will do that.

If a regular user has write access to a directory which contains a file to which the user has just read-only access, that user can effectively take ownership of that file by making a copy of the file in question, deleting the original file and renaming the copy to the original name.

**If new files/directories are unexpectedly created as owned by user `black`, it probably means the process creating them is being executed as that user.** Perhaps some process has been inadvertently started as user `black` instead of as user `company`, or perhaps that user has a cron job or some other automated process in place that creates/manipulates the files.

This is one of the situations where using a standardized service start-up procedure can minimize errors. If you are in the habit of using something like `apachectl start` to directly start up a web server process, it'll be easy to accidentally run that as a wrong user, requiring a clean-up of incorrect permissions after the mistake is corrected. But if you use something like a systemd `.service` which explicitly defines the user which should run the server process, or a start-up script that checks that the service is being run as the correct user before starting it, and always use the standard tool for stopping and starting the service, mistakes like this can be avoided.

Comment: I see, yes I always use `sudo service apache2 restart`, is this causing it to run as the root user? Im not sure how else I should call it