# Is the order of user groups important?

Tags: linux, users, group

I have a user named "black", he is in these groups.

```
groups black
black: www-data sudo
```

Some auto generated files are getting created with the group "sudo" instead of www-data, so I thought changing the order might help. I try to solve the problem I ask [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637372/user-and-group-not-getting-set-correctly-for-auto-generated-files/637569#637569).

Is there a way to change the order of the groups so that **sudo** is the primary group?

Does it even mather?

Comment: I don't think that order shows which group is primary.

Comment: Let us know what issue you are solving by letting `sudo` be the primary group of the user. Note that files created by a user belongs to the primary group of the user.

Comment: To make sudo the primary group, `usermod -g`. As @Kusalananda implies, it might not be a good idea to do that.

Comment: @muru The `groups` command from Linux `coreutils` uses the [`print_group_list()`function](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/group-list.c#n36) which will always print first the real (primary) group, then the effective group if its' different from the real group, then all the supplementary groups.

Comment: @telcoM doesn't seem to be the case for [`groups` from `shadow`](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/groups.c#L71)

Comment: @Kusalananda, some auto generated files are getting created with the group "sudo" instead of www-data, so I thought changing the order might help. I try to solve the problem I ask here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637372/user-and-group-not-getting-set-correctly-for-auto-generated-files?noredirect=1#comment1194133_637372

Comment: @muru Interesting and annoying in equal measure: one more subtle difference to remember in basic low-level tools.

Comment: This might be caused by a typo in user creation: when creating a user with `sudo` access, in Ubuntu and other Linux distributions that use the `sudo` group to grant admin acess, the recommended way might be something like `useradd -G sudo black`. But if a finger slips off the shift key, `useradd -g sudo black` creates a user with `sudo` as the *primary* group, and because `sudo` still works, the error is not immediately apparent... but will affect the default group owner of any files created by that user.

Comment: Figure out groups the way the system does: by reading `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. Read `man -a passwd;man -a group`.

Comment: Consider the History of Unix/Linux. Back in Olden Times we got our `group` from the 3rd field of `/etc/passwd`. When this was found  insufficient, `/etc/group` was added, while maintaining compatibility. `/etc/group` groups could have passwords associated (for the `newgrp` command). Device access, resource access, privileged actions, etc can be managed through groups. In other efforts, passwords were moved to `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/gshadow`.